# How to replace first word of each line in a file with the corresponding element from a list in python?

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
research_t 1:1 2:1 3:1 5:1 13:1 
computer_sc 14:1 19:1 21:1 23:1 25:1 26:1 29:1 36:1 44:1 49:1 50:1 51:1 52:1 57:1 68:1 70:1 71:1 75:1 79:1 
res_computer 1:1 2:1 3:1 5:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 20:1 21:1 22:1
fin_res 23:1 24:1 26:1 28:1 29:1 30:1 32:1 33:1 34:1 35:1 36:1 38:1 39:1 40:1 41:1 43:1 45:1 47:1 48:1 54:1 55:1 56:1 59:1 63:1 64:1 65:1 66:1 72:1 78:1 80:1 
computer_sc_field 2:1 37:1
```

I want to read the file line by line and check it like if the first word in the line has '`computer`' in it, then I want to replace the whole first word by `1`, else replace it by `-1`.

I was doing something like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    wordlist = [line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in f]
    s = 'computer'
    for i in range(len(wordlist)):
        if s in wordlist[i]:
            wordlist[i] = str(1)
        else:
            wordlist[i] = str(-1)
```

Now, I get a list: `[-1, 1, 1, -1, 1]`. But how do I replace the first words of each line in the file with the corresponding element of this list?

Comment: Replacing in a text file is hard. If it's short, it would be much easier to read the whole thing into memory, edit it then write it back out over the original file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the whole line together again, after replacing the first part:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file_in:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as file_out:
        for line in file_in:
            first, other = line.split(None,1)
            line = '%d %s' % (1 if 'computer' in first else -1, other)
            file_out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content = open('file.txt').readlines()
with open('file.txt', 'w') as flux:
    for line in content:
        first_word = line.split()[0]
        new_word = 'computer' in first_word and '1' or '-1'
        flux.write(line.replace(first_word, new_word))
```

ps : answer involving the mode 'rw' is not compatible with python3

Answer (score 0):

I would use the classical tempfile usage and process the file line by line :

```
tmpname = None
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fdin, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
        prefix = 'temp_file', dir='.', delete=False) as fdout:
    tmpname = fdout.name
    for line in fdin:
        first_word, remain = line.split(None, 1)
        fdout.write('1' if 'computer' in first_word else '-1' + ' ' + remain)

os.remove('file.txt')
os.rename(tmpname, 'file.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Through `re` module.

```
import re
with open('input.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if line.startswith('computer'):
                line = re.sub(r'^\S+', r'1', line)
                out_file.write(line)
            else:
                line = re.sub(r'^\S+', r'-1', line)
                out_file.write(line)
```

**Output:**

```
-1 1:1 2:1 3:1 5:1 13:1 
1 14:1 19:1 21:1 23:1 25:1 26:1 29:1 36:1 44:1 49:1 50:1 51:1 52:1 57:1 68:1 70:1 71:1 75:1 79:1 
-1 1:1 2:1 3:1 5:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 20:1 21:1 22:1
-1 23:1 24:1 26:1 28:1 29:1 30:1 32:1 33:1 34:1 35:1 36:1 38:1 39:1 40:1 41:1 43:1 45:1 47:1 48:1 54:1 55:1 56:1 59:1 63:1 64:1 65:1 66:1 72:1 78:1 80:1 
1 2:1 37:1
```